# upload video to facebook group using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using to GRAPH API to upload videos to my pages. I want to upload them to my groups too.

This is what I'm doing to upload video to pages and it is working.

```
$fb = new Facebook([
   'app_id' => APP_ID,
   'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$data = [
   'title' => $title,
   'description' => $description,
   'source' => $fb->videoToUpload(WWW_ROOT . '../' . $path . $file),
];

try {
   $result = $fb->post('/me/videos', $data, $user->access_token);
   return $result;
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
   $response['status'] = false;
   $response['message'] = 'Graph Returned an error: '. $e->getMessage();
   return $response;
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
   $response['status'] = false;
   $response['message'] = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   return $response;
}
```

This is working fine. But not working for group.

**The problem that could be is that I don't have `access_token` of `group` and thus using user's `access_token`**

**How to get `access_token`?**

To get access token of pages, I am doing

```
try {
    $userPages = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $accessToken->getValue());
    $userPages = $userPages->getDecodedBody()['data'];
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

which return an array of pages with `id`, `name`, `category` and `access_token`.

```
[ 
    0 => [
         'name' => 'my page name',
         'category' => 'Education',
         'id' => 1234567890,
         'access_token' => 'hkjh3k42j4j4l1kj4h1lj'
    ],
]
```

But when I get groups using

```
try {
    $userGroups = $fb->get('me/groups', $accessToken->getValue());
    $userGroups = $userGroups->getDecodedBody()['data'];
 } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }
```

I only returns

```
[
    0 => [
       'name' => 'my group name',
       'privacy' => 'OPEN',
       'id' => 1234567890
    ]
]
```

and there is no access token.

**How can I get access token of the group?**

Here `$accessToken->getValue()` is the access_token of user when he authenticates the app.

Comment: _“How can I get access token of the group?”_ – you can’t, because there is no such thing. Whether you can post to a group as a normal user, or only as a group admin, depends on the group’s status (open/closed/private.)

Comment: How to post in OPEN group on behalf of user having access token

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/videos#create